# Is this notation on the restriction of a function in group theory common?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, functions, notation, group-homomorphism

If $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a function between sets $X$ and $Y$, then a common notation to use when we want to restrict $f$ to a certain domain $X' \subset X$ is $f|_{X'}: X' \rightarrow Y$.

I'm doing some group theory and have come across the following:

> Let $G,K$ be groups, $\phi: G \rightarrow K$ a homomorphism, $H \leq G$ a subgroup. Consider $\phi_H$...

Is this common notation (perhaps in group theory)? It wasn't immediately clear to me that this was a restriction to $H$, i.e. $\phi_H: H \rightarrow K$ until I had read the paragraph to the end.

Comment: I believe the usual notation is $\phi|_H$, but this can be used. Also you mean $H \subset G$ i quess from which it follows that $\#H \leq \#G$

Comment: Subset is a requirement for subgroup

Comment: @TimHuijgens The fact that we need $H \subset G$ already comes from the fact that I've said that $H \leq G$ (which is common notation for "$H$ is a subgroup of $G$". It has nothing to do with their sizes).

Comment: @PrinceM ^Similarly for you.

Comment: The usual notation would be $\phi_{\mid H}$. As far as I know the notation $\phi_H$ is not common and has no other obvious meaning. So either it's a simple error or unconventional use of notation, or there is some other obvious meaning to this notation. In which text did you encounter this notation? Maybe that can help us to resolve the issue.

Comment: @IrregularUser I was aware you were saying subgroup, my comment was directed at Tim.

Comment: @Mathematician42 They were in some lecture notes and I don't actually know the common etiquette surrounding the linking of these (they're not behind a login wall). It could be a simple error, though it was used multiple times in the paragraph.

Comment: @PrinceM Ah, it's just that you did ping anyone so I assumed that it was directed at me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a standard notation, though I have seen notation like this used occasionally (not specifically in group theory) when you need to repeatedly refer to lots of restrictions in the course of a single argument.  I would never use a notation like this without defining it for my readers.  The standard notation is $\phi|_H$, not $\phi_H$.

Comment: On the other hand (which is specific to group theory) if the map is a representation or a character then it would be quite common.

Answer (score 0):

I think the restriction $\phi_H$ to $H$  indicated is not only restriction of application, but it seems more, this is a group homomorphism

Comment: I don't understand this. More what? The restriction of a homomorphism is automatically a homomorphism.

Comment: yes , but  the designed  morphism  is the homomorphism  of groups  in this cas,

Comment: I still have no idea what you are trying to say here. Yes, it is a group homomorphism. The notation $\phi_H$ means the restriction to $H$ which is again a group homomorphism. This was not what the question was about.

Comment: sorry for my English, may be language categories seeking to siumplifier things; for this it omitted the vertical bar