# Question on notation for function with different domain

Tags: functions, notation

Consider a function $f$ defined on a rectangle $Q=[a,b] \times [c,d]$. We use the following notation to represent it:

$$f:Q \longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$$

Consider $Q^* \subset Q$

Shall we represent function in domain $Q^*$ as:

$$f:Q^* \longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$$

OR

$$g:Q^* \longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$$

What I mean is : Shall we use another notation $(g)$ to represent the new function whose domain is different?

Comment: You mean the same function $f$ but with the domain restricted only to $Q^*$? Then use $f|_{Q^*}$, $f \mid Q^*$ or $f \upharpoonright Q^*$.

Comment: This question isn't quite a duplicate of [Is this notation on the restriction of a function in group theory common?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1795162/26369). @azifmedrano Could you put that as an answer (maybe add the key word "restriction")?

Comment: @azif00 We need an answer here, for [a recent duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4729046)