# Allen Hatcher's Algebraic Topology -- Unclear statement

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

In this definition (early on):
[image]

He never specifies what $f_t | A = 1$ is supposed to mean in his preamble. What is $|$ being used for in this example?

Comment: I neither downvoted nor voted to close, but I was tempted, since this appears to be a question about set theory which students generally learn before an elementary topology course, let alone an algebraic topology course.

Answer (score 2):

In "Standard Notations" on p. xii Hatcher writes

[image] : the identity function from a set to itself.

The vertical "$\mid$" is the standard notation for the restriction of a function. That is, $f_t\mid A$ denotes the restriction of $f_t :  X \to X$ to the subspace $A \subset X$.